# Date intervals and data manipulation

Tags: r

I'm a new user of R and I'm a little bit stuck, my data looks like this:

```
dates        temp
01/31/2011    40
01/30/2011    34
01/29/2011    30
01/28/2011    52
01/27/2011    39
01/26/2011    37
...
01/01/2011    31
```

i want take only temp under 40 degrees and with the dates of beginning and the end and how many days it lasts, for example:

```
from         to           days
01/29/2011   01/30/2011     2
01/26/2011   01/27/2011     2
```

I tried with difftime but it didn't work, maybe with a function it will.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this. I'll use `data.table` here.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="dates        temp
01/31/2011    40
01/30/2011    34
01/29/2011    30
01/28/2011    52
01/27/2011    39
01/26/2011    37", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt <- dt[, `:=`(date.form = as.Date(dates, format="%m/%d/%Y"), 
          id = cumsum(as.numeric(temp >= 40)))][temp < 40]
dt[, list(from=min(date.form), to=max(date.form), count=.N), by=id]

#    id       from         to count
# 1:  1 2011-01-29 2011-01-30     2
# 2:  2 2011-01-26 2011-01-27     2
```

The idea is to first create a column with the `dates` column converted to `Date` format first. Then, another column `id` that finds the positions where `temp >= 40` and uses that to create the group of values that are within two `temp>=40`. That is, if you have `c(40, 34, 30, 52, 39, 37)`, then you'd want `c(1,1,1,2,2,2)`. That is, everything between to values `>= 40`, must belong to the same group (34, 30 -> 1 and 39, 37 -> 2). After doing this, I'd remove `temp >= 40` entries.

then, you can split by this group and then take `min` and `max` and `length(.)` (which is by default stored in `.N`).

Comment: tyvm, the idea is very clever, i don't why but it says impossible to find "`:=`"!! do i have to load a package or something?

Comment: The package is `data.table`. you'll have to install it. The tick marks enclosing ` := ` are essential and must be included `<tick>:=<tick>(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Not as elegant as Arun's `data.table` but here is `base` solution

```
DF <- read.table(text = "dates        temp\n01/31/2011    40\n01/30/2011    34\n01/29/2011    30\n01/28/2011    52\n01/27/2011    39\n01/26/2011    37", 
    header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF$dates <- as.POSIXct(DF$dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
DF <- DF[order(DF$dates), ]
DF$ID <- cumsum(DF$temp >= 40)
DF2 <- DF[DF$temp < 40, ]

# Explanation split : split DF2 by DF2$ID 
# lapply : apply function on each list element given by split
# rbind : bind all the data together

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(DF2, DF2$ID), function(x) 
            data.frame(from = min(x$dates),  
                       to = max(x$dates), 
                       count = length(x$dates))))
##         from         to count
## 0 2011-01-26 2011-01-27     2
## 1 2011-01-29 2011-01-30     2
```

Comment: another good idea as well!! thanks for help, i added decreasing=TRUE because i wanted the dates in the other way.

Answer (score 3):

First read in the data.  `read.zoo` handles many of the details all in one line including reordering the data to be ascending and converting the dates to `"Date"` class.   If `z` is the resulting zoo object then `coredata(z)` gives the temperatures and `time(z)` gives the dates.

```
Lines <- "
dates        temp
01/31/2011    40
01/30/2011    34
01/29/2011    30
01/28/2011    52
01/27/2011    39
01/26/2011    37
"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

The crux of all this is the use of `rle` which computes `lengths` and `values` from which we can derive all quantities:

```
tt <- time(z)
with(rle(coredata(z) < 40), {
   to <- cumsum(lengths)[values]
   lengths <- lengths[values]
   from <- to - lengths + 1
   data.frame(from = tt[from], to = tt[to], days = lengths)
})
```

Using the first 6 lines of the input data shown we get:

```
       from          to   days
1 2011-01-26 2011-01-27      2
2 2011-01-29 2011-01-30      2
```

Comment: actually, i tried with rle but i couldn't do it, thank you :)